# How can useSWR return undefined when fallbackData is specified?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, i18next, swr

I am using useSWR within a Next.js application to fetch data on the client side to dynamically load data from an external API given a query parameter that specifies the language. However to ensure initial loading of the page, I retrieve data in a default language in `getStaticProps` and specify that data as `fallbackData` in `useSWR`. I then dynamically fetch data based on the currently selected locale using `useSWR`. The data returned by `useSWR` however is undefined despite the fact, that a fallback is specified.

```js
function MyPage({ myFallbackData }) {
  console.log(myFallbackData) // myFallbackData is defined here
 
  const fetcher = async (url) => {
    let result = await fetch(url)
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((myFetchedData) => {
        console.log(myFetchedData) // myFetchedData is defined here 
        return myFetchedData
      })
    console.log("Saved Result")
    console.log(result)
  }

  const { data } = useSWR(
    `https://myapi.com?language=${i18n.language}`, 
    fetcher, 
    { fallbackData: myFallbackData }
  )
  console.log(data) // data is undefined here, however fallbackData was defined for useSWR

  export async function getStaticProps () {
    const res = await fetch('https://myapi.com?language=en') // retrieve default language
    const myFallbackData = await res.json()

    return {
      props: {
        myFallbackData
      }
    }
  }

  return <></>
}
```

I expect `data` to be defined at all times, either as the fallback data or as the fetched data for the specified language.

Answer (score 0):

you need to take `getStaticProps` out of the `MyPage` function.
Also, I'd suggest you to take out `fetcher` as well and use it for both `useSWR` and `getStaticProps`.
Let me know if you need any further support.